# Launching Pentaho Job using a batch file and setting a parameter value

Tags: batch-file, pentaho, jobs

I'm scheduling a Job using a batch file (bat) but I don't know how to set a parameter that the job needs.

hope someone can help me on this! 
My Batch file is:

```
@echo off
set Pentaho_Dir="C:\Transformations&Jobs"
set Pentaho_Job=Interfases_MI.kjb

set path="C:\Program Files\Pentaho\data-integration";%path%

Kitchen.bat /file:%PENTAHO_DIR%\%Pentaho_Job% /log:%PENTAHO_DIR%\Logs\Interfases_MI.log /level:basic
```

Comment: Well. It happens that I figured it out how to write the batch using Kettle params.

Kitchen.bat /file:%PENTAHO_DIR%\%Pentaho_Job% /param:IMPORT=1 /param:PROCESS=1 /param:EXTRACT=0 /param:REPORT=0 /log:%PENTAHO_DIR%\Logs\Interfases_MI.log /level:basic

Hope is useful for anybody.

Answer (score 0):

Since you keep which parameter value is failing to yourself, we resort to guesswork.

I'd try

```
set "Pentaho_Dir=C:\Transformations&Jobs"
set "Pentaho_Job=Interfases_MI.kjb"

set "path=C:\Program Files\Pentaho\data-integration;%path%"
Kitchen.bat /file:"%PENTAHO_DIR%\%Pentaho_Job%" /log:"%PENTAHO_DIR%\Logs\Interfases_MI.log" /level:basic
```

The `set "var=value"` syntax ensures that any trailing spaces on the batch line are not included in the value assigned to `var`. This may not be a problem in the current case, but the resolution of your code would be

```
Kitchen.bat /file:"C:\Transformations&Jobs"\Interfases_MI.kjb /log:"C:\Transformations&Jobs"\Logs\Interfases_MI.log /level:basic
```

Whereas `cmd` would be reasonably happy with the quotes in odd places, `kitchen.bat` may not be.

Comment: Thanks for the advice @Magoo, nevertheless my root question is: How  do I add the param value in that code? I've been making an exhaustive research and Found within Pentaho community this link:

[link](http://infocenter.pentaho.com/help/index.jsp?topic=%2Fpdi_user_guide%2Ftopic_scheudling_scripting.html)

which basically says that I should use /Param:ParamName=Value. Not have tried yet but once I'll do, let you know.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

In windows you can pass the parameters as

```
/param="_destination_email=test@test.com"
```